# Behavior of * in question text

Tags: support, code-formatting, formatting

Typing `*+*` turns into + in the question preview. Why is this, and what should I type to produce `*+*` in plain text instead of a code fragment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get *+* You need to escape the * with \ as * is an italics markdown format character.

`\*+\*` gets rendered into *+*

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) is the SO help on formatting your post.

Comment: Haha, an italics plus sign.  But this bold one __+__ (`__+__` or `**+**`) is actually bold.  It might be helpful to know that the characters surrounded by either asterisks `*` or underscores `_` get bold, italics, or bold-italics formatting.  Basically, see [How to Format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: #+ is a good one as well

Comment: Yep, at least in posts.  It's a lot less impressive in a comment.

Comment: Damn partial markdown support in comments.

Comment: Thanks. The formatting sidebar when you're asking a question doesn't mention asterisks at all.

Comment: @LastStar007 [No, but the convenient help dialog does](http://i.imgur.com/XJrBYqf.png)